# Is it possible to handle BCH transactions on Bitcoin Core wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-cash

I've installed **Bitcoin Core** on a server and it works well for **BTC**. I would like to know can I use the same server and platform to support **BCH** too?
I know that the addresses generated in Bitcoin Core are usable for BCH too. But how if I am able to handle **BCH** transactions in this machine, how can I differ them from **BTC** ones?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your BTC addresses aren't SegWit addresses, you can use `dumpprivkey` to extract your private keys and use them in a BCH wallet. You can import them to Electron Cash, which is a wallet software, or Bitcoin Unlimited/Bitcoin ABC, which are equivalents of Bitcoin Core. I'd advise against using BU/ABC and Core on the same machine, because both of them use the incoming port 8333. Besides, you might need to set `datadir` option otherwise they'd corrupt Core's blockchain and wallet databases.

Comment: do both Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash use the same blockchain too? If so, and if I install both on a same server, how can I differentiate the incoming BTCs from BCHs?

Comment: They have separate blockchains since BCH was born. You need to use different software to receive BCH and BTC, which would tell you which currency you receive.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just something is strange for me. Binance and some other exchanges which I have checked, provide the same address for both BTC and BCH receives. How is it possible? I've got a bit confused.

Comment: There are lots of coins that use the same crypto to sign transactions (ECDSA on curve secp256k1). BTC and BCH included. So you can use the same private key and public keys on both chains (a public key is a private key times the generator point; an address is a hashed public key). Usually different currencies use different address formats. This is to prevent the case that your BCH wallet generates an address that is compatible with both currencies; someone could send BTC to it and those coins could be lost as a result. BCH also has a second address format, but it didn't exist when BCH was

Comment: Created, so you can import the private key from a BTC wallet to BCH wallet or vice versa and use one address for both currencies if you want. If you have a wallet that only lets you receive BCH, I'd suggest that you cashaddr.bitcoincash.org to generate a BCH-only address to avoid someone sending BTC to you by mistake. Are there any other points that I've forgotten to address? @MohammadSaberi

Comment: You gave me lots of information. Thank you so much @MCCCS